# Fail to install Couchbase plugin for ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, couchbase

I have CouchBase 2.5.0 enterprise installed with Elasticsearch 1.0.1. 
I want to install Couchbase plugin on Elasticsearch according to the instructions on http://www.couchbase.com/couchbase-server/connectors/elasticsearch, but it fails.

This is the error I get:

> Installing `couchbaselabs/elasticsearch-transport-couchbase/1.2.0-dp`...
>
> Trying http://download.elasticsearch.org/couchbaselabs/elasticsearch-transport-couchbase/elasticsearch-transport-couchbase-1.2.0-dp.zip...
>
> Trying http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=couchbaselabs/elasticsearch-transport-couchbase/1.2.0-dp/elasticsearch-transport-couchbase-1.2.0-dp.zip...
>
> Trying https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/repositories/releases/content/couchbaselabs/elasticsearch-transport-couchbase/1.2.0-dp/elasticsearch-transport-couchbase-1.2.0-dp.zip...
>
> Trying https://github.com/couchbaselabs/elasticsearch-transport-couchbase/archive/v1.2.0-dp.zip...
>
> Trying https://github.com/couchbaselabs/elasticsearch-transport-couchbase/archive/master.zip...
>
> Downloading .................DONE
>
> Installed `couchbaselabs/elasticsearch-transport-couchbase/1.2.0-dp` into `D:\Install\elasticsearch-1.0.1\plugins\transport-couchbase`
>
> Usage:
>
> ```
> -u, --url     [plugin location]   : Set exact URL to download the plugin from
>
> -i, --install [plugin name]       : Downloads and installs listed plugins [*]
>
> -t, --timeout [duration]          : Timeout setting: 30s, 1m, 1h...
>
> -r, --remove  [plugin name]       : Removes listed plugins
>
> -l, --list                        : List installed plugins
>
> -v, --verbose                     : Prints verbose messages
>
> -s, --silent                      : Run in silent mode
>
> -h, --help                        : Prints this help message
> ```
>
> [*] Plugin name could be:
>
> ```
>  elasticsearch/plugin/version for official elasticsearch plugins (download from download.elasticsearch.org)
>
>  groupId/artifactId/version   for community plugins (download from maven central or oss sonatype)
>
>  username/repository          for site plugins (download from github master)
> ```
>
> Message: **Error while installing plugin, reason:**
>
> **IllegalArgumentException: Plugin installation assumed to be site plugin, but contains source code, aborting installation.**

Why is that ?

10x,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the README of the downloaded master repo that it choked on, it says that they support Couchbase 2.2 (oddly not 2.5) and Elasticsearch 1.0.0 from the `master` repository, and *not* the 1.2.0 release of the plugin.

Try running it using their unlisted `1.3.0-SNAPSHOT` (I found it via URL substitution from their README, which suggested 1.2.0):

```
bin/plugin -install transport-couchbase -url http://packages.couchbase.com.s3.amazonaws.com/releases/elastic-search-adapter/1.3.0/elasticsearch-transport-couchbase-1.3.0-SNAPSHOT.zip
```

Note: They do not *yet* explicitly list this release, but their [pom.xml](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/elasticsearch-transport-couchbase/blame/d012a97344c697b9231dd6dac1182c082e39eb01/pom.xml#L5) lists the [version bump](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/elasticsearch-transport-couchbase/commit/d012a97344c697b9231dd6dac1182c082e39eb01).